# Set Theory : Maximum possible value with some conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

In a class of $60$ students, along with English as a common subject, students can opt to major in Mathematics, Physics, Biology or a combination of any two. $6$ students major in both Mathematics and Physics, $15$ majors in both Physics and Biology but no one majors in both Mathematics and Biology. 
 In an English test, the average marks scored by the students majoring in Mathematics is $45$ and that of students majoring in Biology is $60$. However the combined average marks in English of students of these two majors is $50$. What is the maximum possible number of students who major only in Physics?

My solution approach :- 
Using the average marks given for Mathematics, English and both I figured out that $\Rightarrow$ 
 Number of students in Mathematics $= 2$ (Number of students in Biology) $ = 2y$ ;where $y$ is the number of students in Biology.

Now number of students majoring ONLY in Physics came out to be $60-3y$.

From here onwards I am not able to proceed. Please help!

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation:** For any set $A$, let $N(A)$ indicate the number of students in that set. Let $M$ indicate Maths, $P$ indicate physics, $B$ indicate biology.

You are given that: $N(M\cap P) = 6,N(P\cap B) = 15,N(M\cap B) = 0$. Let the number of students in Maths alone be $x$, biology alone be $y$ and physics alone be $z$.
Then, $x+y+z+6+15=60$, ie $x+y+z = 39$.

Total marks in english of those studying maths = $\mathbb{E}[\text{English score}|M]\cdot N(M) = 45*(x+6) = 45x + 270$. Similarly, total marks in english of those studying biology is $60*(y+15)=60y+900$.

Finally, total marks in english of those studying maths or biology = $\mathbb{E}[\text{English score}|M\cup B]\cdot N(M\cup B) = 50*(x+y+6+15) = 50x + 50y + 1050$.

Since noone studies both maths and biology, the total marks must be the same, irrespective of our counting. Thus $50x+50y+1050 = 45x+270+60y+900$, or $x-2y=24$ (check this is different from what you have obtained).

We have the two equations $x-2y=24$ and $x+y+z = 39$, from which we get $z+3y=15$. Since $y\geq0$, max value of $z$ corresponds to min value of $y$. Thus $z_{max}=15$.

One can check that $\{x,y,z\} = \{24,0,15\}$ is indeed valid

Answer (score 1):

Since at least 15 students are majoring in biology, minimum number of math majors is 30, which comprises 6 math+physics + 24 math-only.

This accounts for 45 of the students, so max number of physics only majors is 15.

Comment: $45$ is the average score on the test, not the number of students

Comment: @saulspatz 45 is the average of the math majors, 60 is the average of the bio majors, 50 is the overall average.  therefore, there must be twice as many math majors.  since there are 15 bio majors there must be 30 math majors.  since there are 60 students overall, with 30 math majors (including the 6 math+physics) and 15 physics+bio, there are only 15 slots left.

Answer (score 1):

Let

- $b$ be the number of students majoring in biology only
- $m$ be the number of students majoring in math only
- $p$ be the number of students majoring in physics only
- $B$ be the total marks scored by those taking biology
- $M$ the total marks scored by those taking math

We have $$\begin {align}
\frac M{m+6}&=45\implies M=45m+270\tag1\\
\frac B{b+15}&=60\implies B=60b+900\tag2\\
\frac{M+B}{m+b+21}&=50\implies M+B=50m+50b+1050\tag3
\end{align}$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives
$$M+B=45m+60b+1170\tag4$$
and now comparing $(3)$ and $(4)$ gives
$$5m=10b+120\implies m=2b+24$$

The total number of students is $60=b+m+p+21$.  To make $p$ as large as possible, take $m$ and $b$ as small as possible, that is, $b= 0, m=24$.  Then $p=15$.

Comment: The answer that has been provided is 15.

Comment: @Ganit  Maybe I misread it.  I'll check.

Comment: but your solution approach seems perfect...!

Comment: @Ganit I reread the problem, and I think my solution is correct.

Comment: small typo: $45*6 \neq 260$, Correcting this, you would get $m = 2b + 24$?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Yes, that's it.